# Unity crashes Web API, no log

Tags: asp.net, unity-game-engine, asp.net-web-api, singleton, inversion-of-control

I want to place my HTML parser into a singleton instance, so I utilized Unity to create and hold my class. Unfortunately this causes the app crash, and I have no information about the error.
I have Elmah but no entry in the datatable.
My bits are:

```
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ElmahErrorAttribute());
            UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
            HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter
                .SerializerSettings
                .ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

        }
```

Controller:

```
    public class AccountsController : BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly ITemplateService _templateService;

        public AccountsController() { }

        public AccountsController(ITemplateService templateService)
        {
            _templateService = templateService;
        }
```

UnityConfig

```
    public static class UnityConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterComponents()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<ITemplateService, TemplateService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
        }
    }
```

No log, no place to set up a breakpoint where the error is, app is crashing.

Answer (score -1):

There is always a log in the **EventViewer**

Open it and there you find what is crash your program.